# Image not displaying in react native

Tags: react-native, laravel-8, cpanel

I'm trying to fetch image from cpanel hosting but not getting image displayed in react native app. I think i'm not getting the exact path from cpanel database.

api is running well it showing image path and other data
other text data is easily displaying in the app but unable to display image

```
i tried this uri
uri: `https://myspace.takexam.com/storage/${item.image}
but not getting the result
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

let tempUri=`https://myspace.takexam.com/storage/${item.image}
console.log(tempUri)

from copy the uri and paste it in browser check if its showing in the browser .

the uri seems to be formatted  okay must be an issue with item.image .